# Running JavaFX application on Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, javafx

I don't know how to launch an application that uses JavaFX on a Docker container.
I'm simply trying to create the jar file with Maven and start it with the Java command but I get this error even though the application starts locally and the JavaFX libraries (javafx-controls and javafx-fxml) are embedded in the jar via dependencies Maven:

```
Nov 03, 2023 2:32:14 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
2023-11-03T14:32:14.602923007Z WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4b55eca5'
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648250579Z Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libprism_es2.so: Error loading shared library libX11.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libprism_es2.so)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648375491Z java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libprism_es2.so: Error loading shared library libX11.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libprism_es2.so)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648493221Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648503060Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648594208Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648603706Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648669381Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648680613Z  at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648735195Z  at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2021)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648873719Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:220)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648883428Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:200)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.648997836Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:142)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649078980Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:58)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649156217Z  at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:63)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649165103Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649172387Z  at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:52)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649176455Z  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649179681Z  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649181605Z  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649303115Z  at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649331429Z  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649338042Z  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.649395333Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660176242Z Loading library glass from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libglass.so: Error loading shared library libX11.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libglass.so)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660200067Z java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libglass.so: Error loading shared library libX11.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.openjfx/cache/22-ea+11/amd64/libglass.so)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660241290Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660250467Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660253934Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660330566Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660342178Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660345634Z  at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660486417Z  at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2021)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660510433Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:220)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660534674Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:200)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660611334Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:142)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660621764Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:58)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660750028Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:112)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660759265Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:120)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660775697Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$static$1(GtkApplication.java:86)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660928126Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660950959Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<clinit>(GtkApplication.java:85)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.660955819Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:40)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661027716Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661037054Z  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661168074Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:292)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661190787Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661257750Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661278339Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661304583Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.661522828Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662193470Z Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glass in java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/lib/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/../lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662230405Z  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:300)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662291592Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:292)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662415748Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662438131Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662504446Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662623713Z  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662647919Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662830747Z Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glass in java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/lib/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto/../lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662855594Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2458)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662861225Z  at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.662864682Z  at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2059)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663023354Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:170)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663046057Z  at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:58)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663053080Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:112)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663080699Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:120)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663089746Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$static$1(GtkApplication.java:86)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663220248Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663243743Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<clinit>(GtkApplication.java:85)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663335068Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:40)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663343614Z  at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663347762Z  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
2023-11-03T14:32:14.663475263Z  ... 6 more
```

**DOCKERFILE**

```
# Build stage
FROM maven:3.9.5-amazoncorretto-21 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# Start stage
FROM amazoncorretto:21-alpine-jdk AS start
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/JavaFXApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /tmp/app.jar
WORKDIR /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: [*Running JavaFx app with Docker containers!*](https://aboullaite.me/javafx-docker/)

Comment: I've already saw this article but it doesn't start a jar file. The article is more about instructing you on how to view the GUI in a Docker container, not how to launch the application

Comment: You need the same command line arguments as you need to run the JavaFX application locally, i.e. you need to specify the location of the JavaFX modules you require and add them. See e.g. "Run HelloWorld using JavaFX" under the [Getting Started JavaFX Docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

Comment: Or, do as in the link in the comment from @BasilBorque and build a distribution of the JavaFX application with the Java runtime bundled (instead of using a jar file).

Comment: Use of `ea` versioned software is not recommended - those are potentially unstable early access versions.  You should choose a JavaFX version that doesn't include the `ea` in the version.

Comment: Your OS version installed by docker appears to be missing dependencies required by JavaFX (e.g. the [X Windows system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), and maybe some others).   See the error message in your log: `Error loading shared library libX11.so.6: No such file or directory`.  Note that the guide Basil provided installs some of these missing dependencies with the command `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y xorg libgl1-mesa-glx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, albeit doing it for a debian based OS rather than an alpine based OS.

Comment: You seem to be using Alpine Linux. It may be difficult to get JavaFX to work with Alpine Linux (I don't know, I haven't tried). Azul Zulu and Bellsoft Liberica both provide JDKs and JREs that include JavaFX, for Windows Mac, and some Linux distributions. But neither produces versions including JavaFX for Alpine Linux. Perhaps this is because it might be difficult to get JavaFX to work on Alpine Linux or support that. Alpine Linux by default uses [musl not glibc](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html), but JavaFX requires glibc as far as I know.